# git server was reverted to old snapshot - how to sync "origin" repos back from devs' PCs?

Tags: git

Long story short, our git server (gitlab if it matters) which hosts about 100 repos got reverted to 3 weeks ago state. We (developers) apparently have all changes made after that on our local computers - that's how GIT works, right? How do we sync them back to the server? The problem I see is that the changes are marked as "pushed" (i.e. in *origin* branch) locally. Will git understand that, and we only need to do push again? how is that going to work with multiple branches? or multiple developers working on the same branch? Any advise or link would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pushing again to the server updates the servers state, as git calculates the diff between the server & client on push

Make sure to push all local branches from your local environment to the server.

*Skip this if your git flow specifies to never checkout to the master branch*

```
git push --all
```

---

In some cases, this might not restore the latest master/develop branch, as some workflows specify that you should never checkout to the master branch at all, if this is your workflow, you should manually push every branch after checking out to the remote version of it. The workflow for recovery then goes like:

```
git checkout master
git merge origin/master
# Don't use pull here or the client will realize the server has "reverted"
git push
```

Answer (score 0):

Stepping back a bit, it sounds like the remote tracking branches on the local (dev) repos being out of sync with the state of the remote (server) repository is what is causing the confusion.

Just do a `git fetch --prune` (or whatever incantation of `fetch` you prefer, but *not* `git pull`), the tracking refs will be updated, and things will start making sense again.